# What is the difference between a normal user and a user created by sacctmgr for some account?

Tags: slurm, sacct

There are some users (listed in /etc/passwd) who can use Slurm to submit jobs in our cluster. But, with sacctmgr we can also define users belonging to some account(s).

What should be the connection of these two group of users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Slurm uses its own user [accounting](https://slurm.schedmd.com/accounting.html) system in order to achieve a clear management of the resources of the cluster. This means you can do things like prevent users for running jobs in other accounts (using [associations](https://slurm.schedmd.com/resource_limits.html)), limit the number of jobs, apply [QOS](https://slurm.schedmd.com/qos.html), etc. If the user is not defined in the Slurm accounting system you are not taking advantage of those features of Slurm. Check the [man](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacctmgr.html) for more information.

> What should be the connection between these two groups of users?

It mostly depends in the policies and management that you want to have in the cluster. It is **not** mandatory to run Slurm using the database (e.g It can use a plain text file) but it will limit the possibilities that you have to manage your resources. I would recommend to map all the users in your system (the list of */etc/passwd*) to the Slurm data base, in case you want to have any special behavior/constrain over your users in the future.